# убрать href ссылки для media print

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap, print

При отправки страницы на печать в предварительном просмотре отображаются якоря ссылок возле каждой ссылки, возможно ли как-то отключить эту функцию?

Comment: Думаю, имеет смысл добавить к вопросу метку [tag:bootstrap].

Answer (score 5):

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

Разумеется, при этом это переопределение должно идти после стилей бутстрапа.

Answer (score 3):

Сам решил проблему, буду рад если кому то поможет

```
a:after{
    content: "" !important;
}
```